# gpuIncreaseOne Function Implementation in CUDA

Tags: beginner, c, reinventing-the-wheel, cuda

I am trying to perform the basic operations `+` with CUDA for GPU computation. The function `vectorIncreaseOne` is the instance for the operation details and `gpuIncreaseOne` function is the structure for applying the operation to each element in the parameter `data_for_calculation`.

**The experimental implementation**

The experimental implementation of `gpuIncreaseOne` function is as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#include <math.h>

__global__ void CUDACalculation::vectorIncreaseOne(const long double* input, long double* output, int numElements)
{
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < numElements)
    {
        if (input[i] < 255)
        {
            output[i] = input[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}

int CUDACalculation::gpuIncreaseOne(float* data_for_calculation, int size)
{
    // Error code to check return values for CUDA calls
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

    // Print the vector length to be used, and compute its size
    int numElements = size;
    size_t DataSize = numElements * sizeof(float);

    // Allocate the device input vector A
    float *d_A = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A, DataSize);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device input vector B
    float *d_B = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_B, DataSize);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allocate the device output vector C
    float *d_C = NULL;
    err = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, DataSize);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Copy the host input vectors A and B in host memory to the device input vectors in
    // device memory
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, data_for_calculation, DataSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Launch the Vector Add CUDA Kernel
    int threadsPerBlock = 256;
    int blocksPerGrid =(numElements + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);
    vectorIncreaseOne <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_A, d_C, numElements);

    err = cudaGetLastError();

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch vectorAdd kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Copy the device result vector in device memory to the host result vector
    // in host memory.
    err = cudaMemcpy(data_for_calculation, d_C, DataSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector C from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Free device global memory
    err = cudaFree(d_A);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaFree(d_B);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector B (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    err = cudaFree(d_C);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Test cases**

The test case for `gpuIncreaseOne` function is as below.

```
auto data_pointer = (float*)malloc(100 * sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    data_pointer[i] = static_cast<float>(1);
}
CUDACalculation::gpuIncreaseOne(data_pointer, 100);


free(data_pointer);
```

All suggestions are welcome.

If there is any possible improvement about:

- Potential drawback or unnecessary overhead
- Error handling

please let me know.